# Can I use multilpe EF Entities in a IQueryable to implement paging?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `Get` method that has working paging but I also want to create a method that can return multiple entities of the same base type and still have paging.

I know this has to translate to SQL somehow which I guess would have to be returned as multiple result sets.

```
// Model classes
public class Food 
{
    string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Fruit : Food  
{
    bool IsSweet {get;set;}
}

public class Vegetable : Food 
{
    bool IsGross {get;set;}
}

// FruitRepo -- BLL layer
public List<Fruit> GetFruit(int userId, int page, int itemsPerPage)
{
    var query = repo.Get<Fruit>(e => e.userId == userId);
    var dbResults = query.Skip((itemsPerPage * page) - itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage).ToList();
    return dbResults;
}

// FoodRepo -- BLL layer
public List<Food> GetFood(int userId, int page, int itemsPerPage)
{
    // How can I use IQuerable here to implement paging correctly?

    List<Food> rv = new List<Food>();

    var repo = new Repo();
    rv.AddRange(repo.Get<Fruit>(e => e.userId == userId).ToList());
    rv.AddRange(repo.Get<Vegetable>(e => e.userId == userId).ToList());

    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you modeled the entities in EF.
EF can follow [different strategies with inheritance](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

If the inherited classes are simmilar I usually choose *table per hierachy*.
The selected strategy can impact in SQL perfomance, but you can abstract at business logic of the selected strategy.

You only need to call EF once to fill the list and EF reintegrates the data into the corresponding inherited class:

```
repo.Get<Food>(e => e.userId == userId).ToList());
```

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for. I've always done the Table per Entity way but this looks very promising. The only possible downside I see is combining many tables/entities can make for a really wide table, any other things or limitations to be aware of code or DB side?

Comment: Table-Per-Type vs Table-Per-Hierarchy shouldn't have *any* effect on how the results are paged.  You should be able to do your paging with either inheritance pattern.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I meant any effects in general, not specific to paging.

Comment: Downside effects depends on the selected strategy and the differences between the inherited classes. Yes, combining many entities with many different properties, you'll obtain a wide table; but if your entities has common properties, the resulting table will be ok. It also depends on your queries: are you allways query for al `Food` classes or you'll frecuentlly ask for a `Fruits`. If your queries are only for a inherited class, perhaps `Table per Concrete Type`is your choice

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a `List<T>` from your BLL, return a `PagedList<T>`, which, among other things, can include a page count:

```
Public class PagedList<T> {
  public List<T> Results { get; set; }
  public int PageNumber { get; set; }
  public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `GetFruit`/`GetFood` methods can look like this:

```
public List<Fruit> GetFruit(int userId, int page, int itemsPerPage)
{
    var query = repo.Get<Fruit>(e => e.userId == userId);
    var dbResults = query.Skip((itemsPerPage * page) - itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage).ToList();
    return new PagedList<Fruit>()
    {
         Results = dbResults,
         PageNumber = page,
         TotalCount = query.Count(),
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually have that in my code already. I just simplified the example to focus on a different problem. I need to somehow combine `Fruit` and `Vegetable` and be correctly paged from EF. I believe the inheritance answer @mnieto posted is more in the correct direction.

Comment: @user3953989 It's unclear from your post if `Food` is a base *entity* or just base class.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't believe I know the difference. Currently it's just a base class (only exists in code).

Comment: Base entity means it's part of EF inheritance strategy. According to your comments, it's not.